# running mpi on OS X

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I'm parallelizing some python code on my laptop.
It's a OS X macbook pro.
while running the simple hello world code I notice I'm getting the same number for all processes is this correct? or I have configured something wrong?

```
from mpi4py import MPI

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    myrank = comm.Get_rank() 
    nproc = comm.Get_size()
    print("Hello, World ! from process {0} of {1} \n"
        .format(myrank , nproc))

Hello, World ! from process 0 of 1

Hello, World ! from process 0 of 1

Hello, World ! from process 0 of 1

Hello, World ! from process 0 of 1
```

Here's how my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       bobs.local
```

I have installed mpi using home-brew and I run the scripts as

```
mpiexec -n 4 python 2.py
```

Comment: How did you install mpi4py and how are you calling it? For what it's worth I can run your example on debian (with pip installed mpi4py) and it prints 4 different process ranks as expected.

Comment: that typically occurs when `mpirun` and `libmpi.so` do not match, for example if you are running `mpirun` from MPICH, but `mpi4py` is using `libmpi.so` from Open MPI under the hood.

Comment: how can I fix this issue?

Comment: you first need to figure out which `mpiexec` is used, and which MPI library `mpi4py` is using.